# Kafka Streams job with significant disk IO

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I'm having issues with a KStreams job consuming a tremendous amount of disk IO. This is an Azure VM with max IOPS of 500 and it's eating up around 500tps (from `iostat` in RHEL) to process 400 records per second. The job ingests records from a Kafka topic (12 partitions), deconstructs a JSON string and does some processing (string searches, replacement, and data enrichment), then delivers it to a Kafka sink (6 partitions). That said, as far as I know this work should be stateless and should not require RocksDB or other state stores.

I have `commit.interval.ms=60000` (1 minute), set in `Properties` as `StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG=60000`, and I've tried other settings and this does not seem to impact the disk IO or how often we see writes to checkpoint.tmp. I've tried running anywhere from 1 to 12 threads, using `StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG`. The IO and number of records per second this job can process is directly impacted by the number of threads, more threads means higher IO and throughput. I have turned off all logging (DEBUG, INFO, etc...), so there should be no IO there. As far as I can tell, the job is constantly committing to `checkpoint.tmp`, and also hitting `imjournal.state.tmp` a whole lot. I get this information by using `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump` to turn on logging, then `dmesg -wH` to see what's going on. Below is a small sample of what I see when I'm looking at `dmesg`.

Does anyone have tips on settings I can try or where else I can look to figure out what's causing this much IO?

Thanks in advance.

```
[ +0.001097] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351525 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351525 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.005463] java(73280): dirtied inode 17178982 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000003] java(73280): dirtied inode 17178982 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000022] java(73280): WRITE block 16922536 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000134] java(73280): WRITE block 33057066 on sda2 (14 sectors)
[ +0.000855] java(73284): dirtied inode 17178985 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000001] java(73281): dirtied inode 51158861 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] java(73281): dirtied inode 51158861 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] java(73284): dirtied inode 17178985 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000017] java(73284): WRITE block 16922544 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000000] java(73281): WRITE block 50389296 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000184] java(73282): dirtied inode 892020 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000000] java(73283): dirtied inode 51158863 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] java(73283): dirtied inode 51158863 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] java(73282): dirtied inode 892020 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000015] java(73282): WRITE block 1140808 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000001] java(73283): WRITE block 50389304 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000576] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351527 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351527 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000671] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351525 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351525 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.001975] java(73285): dirtied inode 35443635 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] java(73285): dirtied inode 35443635 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000015] java(73285): WRITE block 34930256 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.001344] java(73282): WRITE block 33057080 on sda2 (23 sectors)
[ +0.006529] java(73280): dirtied inode 17178984 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000003] java(73280): dirtied inode 17178984 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000016] java(73280): WRITE block 16922280 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.002142] java(73280): WRITE block 33057103 on sda2 (7 sectors)
[ +0.001010] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351527 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000003] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351527 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.003449] java(73281): dirtied inode 51158862 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000000] java(73284): dirtied inode 17178983 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] java(73284): dirtied inode 17178983 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000003] java(73281): dirtied inode 51158862 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000017] java(73281): WRITE block 50389280 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000001] java(73284): WRITE block 16924528 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000224] java(73283): dirtied inode 51158864 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000003] java(73283): dirtied inode 51158864 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000001] java(73285): dirtied inode 35443622 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000001] java(73285): dirtied inode 35443622 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000016] java(73283): WRITE block 50389376 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000001] java(73285): WRITE block 34930264 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000171] java(73282): dirtied inode 892021 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000003] java(73282): dirtied inode 892021 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000018] java(73282): WRITE block 1140824 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000331] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351525 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000003] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351525 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000351] java(73284): WRITE block 33057110 on sda2 (25 sectors)
[ +0.000357] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351527 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351527 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.004964] java(73280): dirtied inode 17178982 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] java(73280): dirtied inode 17178982 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000018] java(73280): WRITE block 16922728 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000996] java(73285): WRITE block 33057135 on sda2 (26 sectors)
[ +0.004757] java(73284): dirtied inode 17178985 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] java(73284): dirtied inode 17178985 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000016] java(73284): WRITE block 16922720 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000310] java(73281): dirtied inode 51158861 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] java(73281): dirtied inode 51158861 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000015] java(73281): WRITE block 50389288 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.001163] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351525 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000003] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351525 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000082] java(73284): WRITE block 33057161 on sda2 (17 sectors)
[ +0.004419] java(73285): dirtied inode 35443635 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000003] java(73285): dirtied inode 35443635 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000018] java(73285): WRITE block 34930280 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000357] java(73282): dirtied inode 892020 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000003] java(73282): dirtied inode 892020 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000017] java(73283): dirtied inode 51158863 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] java(73283): dirtied inode 51158863 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] java(73282): WRITE block 1140816 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000012] java(73283): WRITE block 50389272 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000237] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351527 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000003] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351527 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000530] java(73280): dirtied inode 17178984 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000002] java(73280): dirtied inode 17178984 (.checkpoint.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000027] java(73280): WRITE block 16922536 on sda2 (8 sectors)
[ +0.000465] java(73285): WRITE block 33057178 on sda2 (38 sectors)
[ +0.000637] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351525 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
[ +0.000003] in:imjournal(1190): dirtied inode 50351525 (imjournal.state.tmp) on sda2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a conversation in Slack with the Confluent Community I realized I was running org.apache.kafka -> kafka-streams -> 1.0.2.  The latest version of this framework is 2.3.0 so I upgraded my app to 2.2.1 and tried again.  That version of the app runs with almost no noticeable tps or iowait and with 1 app, spawning 12 threads (thread count is the same as my partition count), I was able to process up to 1,800 records per second. I them bumped the app to 2.3.0 and had the same results, so I'm staying on this version for a bit.

I'm not 100% sure **why** the upgrade fixed it, but I'm going to assume it's related to checkpointing changes the dev team made in the newer version.

Comment: You may want to accept your own answer. Happy to hear, that Kafka Streams work so much better in newer version :)